# Get user info from token c#

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, dotnetopenauth

i have successfully got the key token for the above oauth authentication from Google provider  through their api.

let us consider **"access-token"** is xxxii-xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx which has scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

now when i hit the browser with access token for retrieving user information values has

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=xxxii-xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx;
```

i am getting responses as

```
{
 "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
 "name": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
 "given_name": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
 "family_name": "X",
 "picture": "XXXXXXXXXX/photo.jpg",
 "locale": "en"
}
```

My problem is when i parse the above request through code i am not  getting responses as i got through browser

the code which i used is

```
String userInfo = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token="+token;
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(userInfo);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

sr.Close();

JObject jsonResp = JObject.Parse(userInfo);
string info = "";
info += "<h3>" + jsonResp.Root["name"] + "</h3>";
info += "<img src='" + jsonResp.Root["picture"] + "' width='120'/><br/>";
info += "<br/>ID : " + jsonResp.Root["id"];
info += "<br/>Email : " + jsonResp.Root["email"];

Response.Write(info);
```

in response i am getting null reference .

and the error i got in the line

```
JObject jsonResp = JObject.Parse(userInfo);
```

as

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Line 1, position 1.

Stack trace:

> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue(Char currentChar)
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader)
>          at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json)
>          at _Default.getresponse(String token) in d:\Oauth\WebSite3\Default.aspx.cs:line 99

Waiting for your valuable suggestions and comments

Comment: You're parsing the url `userInfo`, not the response `sr`.

Comment: @Caramiriel i am getting nul response from sr

Comment: Could you inspect `HttpWebResponse resp` and add your findings to the question? Maybe it returns a HTTP 404 or 500 status.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code to get user info:

```
var userInfoUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"; 
var hc = new HttpClient();
hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
var response = hc.GetAsync(userInfoUrl).Result;
dynamic userInfo = response.Content.ReadAsAsync().Result;
return userInfo;
```

There is a good article about integration of dotnetopenoauth and google api: http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/documentation/securityscenarios/

Comment: can you please share the reference dll names for above method

Comment: They all are part of .net: System.Net.Http.dll